# Beginner: Static Methods

Tags: java

I am asked to "Write a static method which, given a String as an input parameter, will return another String representing the input string with all vowels removed."

I'm not exactly sure what they mean by this. I wrote this below. What would I need to change to the answer? Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Hello there";
    String s1 = s.replaceAll("[AaEeIiOoUu]", "");
    System.out.print(s1);
}
```

Comment: Does your method do what the exercise statement expects?

Comment: Create a class, inside write a method "public static String myMethod(String s) { ... }" and inside return the converted string, don't print it.

Comment: I believe you are expected to write a static method that can be called, what you have is a main method, which always executes once you  compile and run the code. There's loads of resources online that you may find helpful, google static methods, method signatures, return types etc.

Comment: Well yes it removes all vowels. But I'm confused as to whether I need to do anything different for a "static method" and "input parameter"? Have I done this?? I don't really understand the terms!

Comment: @user3245026: "Write a static method" Nope, you didn't write that yet. Read between the lines. You need just a static method outside of main.

Comment: Static method means a method is "bound to a class", that is you don't need an instance of a class (aka an object) to run it. The keyword static means the method is static. Input param is the argument / arguments list. You need to copy your code into an isolated method (have a look at the first comment, the method signature is correct) and instead of printing s1 you should return it: return s1;

Answer (score 2):

Check answers from @NicksTyagi and others for the static method. However, I wanted to point out that you can optimize your regex like this: `(?i)[aeiouy]`.

`(?i)` is an inline flag that indicates that the part of the regex that follows it, is case **i**nsensitive. By using this flag it's not necessary to put the letters in upper case.

Feel free to remove the `y` from the regex if it isn't considered as a vowel in your language.

#### Sample code

```
public static String removeVowels(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("(?i)[aeiouy]", "");
}
```

Comment: It might be useful for the OP to explain to him what the `(?i)` actually does.

Comment: The way I learned it in first grade, it should be `"(?i)[aeiou and sometimes y]"` ... :) :) "y" isn't always a vowel, and it would be way too tough to ask a beginner to write a program to determine when it is and when it isn't.  At least they're not asking the program to remove the one vowel in the word "crwth".  (Yes, that's a word.)

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you're from France and maybe "y" _is_ always a vowel there.  Not in English, though.

Comment: @skiwi I have updated my answer with an explication about `(?i)`.

Comment: @ajb You're right `y` is a vowel in french. BTW, I *sometimes* forget that I'm on a english site ... ooops :)

Comment: It's lovely to see an answer that teaches us something about another language or country, not just something about programming.  This answer and the discussion below it has put a smile on my face.

Answer (score 1):

The static method you copied and pasted into your question is called main. It's kind of special, it takes a `string[]` as an argument, and it always returns void. In order to complete your assignment, you need to write *another* static method.

First, you need to **give it a name**.

```
static myFunction() {
}
```

Next, **give it a return (output) type**. Your assignment was to return a `String`.

```
static String myfunction() {
}
```

Then, you need to let it **accept a parameter (input)** of type `String`.

```
static String myFunction(String input) {
}
```

Almost last, we'll add in the logic to **transform the input into an output**.

```
static String myFunction(String input) {
    input = input.replaceAll("[AaEeIiOoUu]", "");
}
```

Finally, we need to **return the output**.

```
static String myFunction(String input) {
    String output = input.replaceAll("[AaEeIiOoUu]", "");
    return output;
}
```

Viola. You are done! You won't need to know much more about the static keyword until you study object-oriented programming. The correct definition is that static methods are bound to a class, while non-static methods are bound to an *instance* of a class. Here is a gruesome example.

- A static method could accept a Person and return a Person with all of its arms chopped off.
- I am a person. I could use my very own non-static method to remove all of my arms.

Hope that helps you remember!

Answer (score 0):

The class must be as below :

```
public class Demo {

        public static String replaceVowel(String input)
        {
            input = input.replaceAll("[AaEeIiOoUu]", "");
            return input;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
          String output =  Demo.replaceVowel("Hello World");
          System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create another method with the static keyword. Call this method from main.

```
 public static void main(Strings args[]){
    removeVowels("Hello World");
}

public static String removeVowels(String textWithVowels){
    return textWithVowels.replaceAll("[AaEeIiOoUu]", "");
}
```